# Changing Object Variables in Java OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'll try to keep it short, I have a class that draws a player by calling the class Cube to make a Head, a Body, two arms, and two legs, each with different variables defined in my constructor. But calling head.r = 1.0f doesn't change the color at all, is it because my cube method pushes and pops the matrix?

Head portion of Player class

```
    head = new Cube(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, h_x, h_y, h_z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, h_length, h_height, h_width);
    head.cube(drawable);


    head.r = 1.0f;
```

Cube method

```
public void cube(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glPushMatrix();

    gl.glColor3f(r, g, b);
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    gl.glRotatef(angle, pitch, yaw, roll);
    gl.glScalef(length, height, width);
    gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    //front
    gl.glVertex3f(c, c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, -c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, -c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, c, c);
    //back
    gl.glVertex3f(c, c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, -c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, -c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, c, -c);
    //top
    gl.glVertex3f(c, c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, c, c);
    //bottom
    gl.glVertex3f(c, -c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, -c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, -c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, -c, c);
    //left
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, -c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, -c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(-c, c, -c);
    //right
    gl.glVertex3f(c, c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, -c, c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, -c, -c);
    gl.glVertex3f(c, c, -c);

    gl.glEnd();

    gl.glPopMatrix();

}
```

P.S. To avoid confusion, the class is Cube and the method is cube.

Edit: I tried commenting out the push and the pop, and it messes everything up but the color of the head **still** doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I was using JOGL Objects incorrectly, due to JOGL's looping I was drawing before changing color, but defining the head in the constructor of my player class and then changing head.r yielded color change. Unfortunately it did not fix my overall issue. Go ahead and close this question, sorry for the time waste. I hope this helps other people.